# How do I create ground voltage for my op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, voltage-divider, virtual-ground, split-supply

[image]

I am trying to create a practical Wien Bridge Oscillator and I created a simulation for it. Everything works fine in the simulation.

Then I proceed the real part. Since I have only one power supply, I created a very simple voltage divider and used the middle as ground. It didn't work. I tried the same setup at the simulator and it really didn't work.

So how can I simply create a ground voltage for my op-amp?

[image]

Edit: I tried this as voltage divider. It works with a DC generator signal and ground but not with a DC source or battery.

Comment: Buffer that divider output with another opamp before using it.

Comment: Or use two voltage sources, positive and negative

Comment: I dont know how to create negative voltage source

Comment: I saw some buffering yeah but it seems that those buffer circuits need AC voltage anyway

Comment: @Tombeki What you just said doesn't make sense. Just stick a opamp voltage follower between the output of your divider and the rest of the circuit. You might need some noise in your circuit to kick start the oscillation. There is always noise in a real circuit so this isn't a problem in real life but yours is a squeak clean simulation.

Comment: I edited the post. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Tombeki Yeah...

Comment: @DKNguyen guess what! It doesnt work :D It works in the simulation but not in real circuit. As far as I know the frequency of a Wien Bridge Oscillator is 1/2piRC. According to this frequency of this oscillator should be around 12Hz when I use 1uF capacitors and 10k resistors. 12Hz is a pretty observable oscillation but my led keeps lighting constantly.

Comment: @Tombeki, do you have a clear idea how to control an LED?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I know that it supports around 10mA 1.8-3.3V and it is actually a diode. Other than this, I know nothing :D Would be glad if you help me.

Comment: @Tombeki, "it supports around 10mA 1.8-3.3V" but you have applied +-9 V across it...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist in virtual oscilloscope my peak voltage is 2.5

Comment: @Tombeki, However, it is not good not to have a resistor in series to the LED...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I actually added 220ohm resistor in my real circuit but the result is the same so I didnt add it in. Will consider it next time tho. So any idea why my oscillator is not working?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist adding a resistor broke my simulation :D god this is interesting!

Comment: See my Wien Oscillator design answer in your other question, It runs off a single supply and uses a buffered supply-splitter to do so. Also, are you trying to use polarised electrolytic 1uF caps in your real circuit?

Comment: @Tombeki,  As far as I know, you have to insert some non-linear element (e.g., diode, lamp) into the negative feefback loop (R1, R2). See, for example, this [RG question](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-the-basic-idea-of-Wien-bridge-oscillator-How-does-it-operate).

Comment: The opamp needs to be able to source and sink enough current for whatever your circuit using. Might need pass transistors.

Comment: @James I especially chose unpolarized capacitors so no. I will check the design but what I really wonder is why this design doesnt work, I basically did the same thing.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist thats what I thought but the design is this simple and it works in simulaton. kinda.

Comment: @DKNguyem Im so new with the terminology, what do you mean by pass transistors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"virtual ground" ICs exist [and are a great option](https://www.ti.com/product/TLE2426).

Another common trick is to create a virtual ground  using a spare opamp section:

[image: schematic]

sometimes you can even get away without the opamp section, depends on how stiff you need the "ground" rail to be.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to approach the power supply to an opamp, which is traditionally dual, but for obvious reasons of convenience often you don't have a negative rail.

- Use a different circuit topology. Most of the usual circuits (amplifiers, integrators, etc) for opamps are easily modifiable for running with a single supply; maybe the Wien bridge is tricky, I never used it, but AB-111 from Analog Devices has the schematic and some explanation;
- Use a rail splitter: I only seen this from TI but essentially you give it like 10V and it gives you a stiff 5V rail to use as ground for the circuit: more or less what you tried but better engineered (as in, better output impedance);
- Create the negative rail yourself: opamp circuits usually don't need a lot of power, so just use an inverting charge pump to make a negative rail; from the old 7660 to the newer regulated low noise parts it's quite easy to do. If you have a lot of analog signal chain it could be even a good idea to use an inductive converter (more power)

Comment: I managed to create one, it works in the simulator too but the real circuit doesnt work